# Add an effect with a css change (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I have an image, and when I hover it, the image disappear and the text is displayed. But I want to add an effect like `fadeIn()` but it doesn't work.

I have this code :

```
$('.gridImage').hover(function(){
   $(this).find("img").css("visibility","hidden");
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").css("visibility","visible");
});
```

I tried with  `$(this).find("img").css("visibility","hidden").fadeIn(1000);` but it doesn't work. Can someone help me please ?

EDIT :

```
    <div class="col-md-15 col-lg-15 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 gridImage">
        <img src="images/bonheur.jpg" class="img-responsive gridImage couple1" id="">
        <div class="projet text-uppercase">Voir le projet</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the `visibility` in CSS means that the image will instantly become invisible. Use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` by themselves instead:

```
$('.gridImage').hover(function(){
   $(this).find("img").fadeOut()
}, function(){
    $(this).find("img").fadeIn()
});
```

Or simply just [`fadeToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/) under both events:

```
$('.gridImage').hover(function(){
   $(this).find("img").fadeToggle()
});
```

Also note that you can do this in CSS alone without the need for any JS code:

```
.gridImage img {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.gridImage:hover img {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fadeIn()` is already animating from `display: none` to `display: inline` (in this case, because it's a `<span>`) , if you want to animate `visibility`, use `animate()`

Here a simple demo with `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()`

```js
$('.gridImage').hover(function() {

  $(this).children("img").fadeOut(1000, function() {
    $(this).siblings("span").fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
span.text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gridImage">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg" />
  <span class="text">THIS IS GRUMPY CAT!</span>
</div>
```